# How do I make a text clipping mask with video on non-black/white background

Tags: css, html5-video

I'm looking to have text act as a clipping mask for a background video, like shown here: https://codepen.io/corvus-007/pen/vYEXLmg, which uses the `mix-blend-mode: darken` filter to create the effect.

My problem is that this method seems like it only works when the background is either black or white. The background of my page has a hex value of #161616, and when I try using the method above, I can still see the filtered video outside of the text.

Does anyone know the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use another `h2` element to put over with `color:#fff` and `mix-blend-mode:multiply`:

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 28vw;
  text-align: center;
  animation: anim-text-color 16s infinite linear;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

#h2 {
  color: #fff;
  animation: none;
  background-color: #161616;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

@keyframes anim-text-color {
  0%,
  100% {
    color: #36b5b0;
  }
  20% {
    color: #380e7f;
  }
  40% {
    color: #6915cf;
  }
  60% {
    color: #d62196;
  }
  80% {
    color: #6807f9;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4%2FOne-Swan.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <h2>video</h2>
  <h2 id="h2">video</h2>
</div>
```